# TradingView webhooks to Discord via Alert Message box - embedded URL link incorrect

Tags: discord, pine-script, webhooks, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have written the indicator / strategy in Pinescript.
Added it to a chart in TradingView
And then added an alert to it where I can put in JSON format a customized message.
And then the alert gets sent via webhook to Discord channel

```
{
"content": "***BTC***\n[__*{{exchange}}:{{ticker}}*__](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/XXXXXX/)\nOrder to {{strategy.order.action}} {{strategy.order.contracts}} clip filled. \n@Price ={{close}}. \nNew strategy position is {{strategy.position_size}}\n\nDateTime: {{timenow}}.\nInterval = {{interval}} mins\n\n### end of message ##\n ","parse_mode": "Markdown"
}
```

The light formatting etc comes out fine - but, for some reason the "/chart" from https://www.tradingview.com/chart/XXXXXX/ URL is ommitted - shows as https://www.tradingview.com/XXXXXX/

resulting in being directed to an invalid page/link.
Not entirely sure if i've done anything wrong or missed something